# Fixed effects model with dummy variables

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, clustered-standard-errors, plm

I have to set up a regression analysis of panel data with a dummy variable (1 or 0) and fixed effects (for example time).

Could someone help me how to do this in R?
For now, I have set the dataset as a panel data set via `pdata.frame` of the package `plm`. As index, I choose the specific code of each fund as well as the year.

```r
library("plm")
PData <- pdata.frame(Data, index = c("code", "yy"))

regression <- plm(DependentVariable ~ Variable1 + Variable2 + 
    Factor(Dummy), data = Dataset, model = "within", 
    effect = "individual") 
summary(regression)
```

Are the years/codes now seen as fixed effects? And how do I implement clustered standard errors? And is (Dummy) now seen as dummy variable?

Comment: Welcome. Just to be clear, is `yy` your year variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are the years/codes now seen as fixed effects?

The model is estimating `code` fixed effects.

By specifying `model = "within"` you're estimating a *fixed effects* model, but it's actually the next argument that tells the function to estimate fixed effects for individual, time, or both. In your case, by specifying `effect = "individual"` you're estimating a one-way individual (i.e., code) fixed effects model. If you want year fixed effects, then specify `effect = "time"`. If you want both, then specify `effect = "twoways`. I reproduced your code to show you the different ways to manipulate the `effect = ...` argument.

Again, if you want code *and* year fixed effects, then go with the third model.

```
# code fixed effects

plm(DependentVariable ~ Variable1 + Variable2 + factor(Dummy), data = PData, model = "within", effect = "individual")

# year fixed effects

plm(DependentVariable ~ Variable1 + Variable2 + factor(Dummy), data = PData, model = "within", effect = "time")

# code and year fixed effects

plm(DependentVariable ~ Variable1 + Variable2 + factor(Dummy), data = PData, model = "within", effect = "twoways")
```

Lastly, you should pass `PData` to the `data = ...` argument.

> And how do I implement clustered standard errors ?

It depends on *how* you want to cluster. For Huber–White standard errors clustered by `code`, try this

```
library(lmtest)

coeftest(regression, vcov = vcovHC(regression, type = "HC0", cluster = "group"))
```

where `regression` is your stored fixed effects results from `plm`.

> And is (Dummy) now seen as a dummy variable ?

Yes.

Please note that `Factor(Dummy)` will return an error. Instead, use `factor(dummy)`. Also, if `Dummy` is truly a 0/1 variable, then wrapping it in `factor()` is unnecessary; simply use `Dummy` *as is* inside of the model formula. If, on the other hand, it's not a 0/1 variable but instead is a multivalued categorical variable with many levels, then `factor(Dummy)` should work fine; it will 'dummy out' the $N - 1$ categories for you.

Comment: Wow thank you ! 
However, today I was told to instead do it with the felm function.

So, I know how to put the fixed effects in it as well as the clustered standard errors. But how do I include a lag into this regression analysis ? :/

Comment: No problem. Do you want to include a lag using `plm`?

Comment: Is this possible within the felm function ? I just have to put in a lag, but I don´t know how to code it correctly.

Comment: felm(Formula(Variables) | code, time | 0 | ID, time)
In my table, the code as well as the time are given. However, somehow, R says that there is no object named like that, although it actually is. Do you maybe know why ? :/

Comment: I would ask a new question and link it here. I will get to it. In the meantime, if my answer helped, please consider giving it a check.

Comment: I gave you a check, and do you mean I should post a new question about the felm function ? :)

Comment: Yes. However, if it's narrowly related to programming, then StackOverflow is a better alternative.